# PHP Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers

Tags: php, soap, header

I'm building a fairly simple SOAP call but I'm running into an error.  I can't seem to figure out what the deal is.  I've done this numerous times so there has to be a disconnect somewhere or something I am missing..

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 5000);



$client = new SoapClient("http://server.com:8080/CustomerCareService.svc?wsdl",array('trace'=>true,'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,'keep_alive'=>true,'enco$
        //      var_dump($client->__getFunctions());

echo $client->GetCustomerAccountByPhone(array('phoneNumber'=>'12223334444'));
```

Comment: Did you check that the server behaves correctly?

Comment: In addition use `try/catch` blocks to handler the error(s) properly.

Comment: Yes - I get the below.  SOAP Fault: (faultcode: HTTP, faultstring: Error Fetching http headers)



`try {
    $client = new SoapClient("http://server.com:8080/CustomerCareService.svc?wsdl",array('trace'=>true,'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
    $result = $client->GetCustomerAccountByPhone(array('phoneNumber'=>'1112223333'));
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
}`

Comment: @hagello, I can retrieve the functions no problems.  The issue I have is once I try to call a function.